# Subtract two timestamptz values and insert the result into a third column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE duration
(
departure_time TIMESTAMPTZ, 
arrival_time TIMESTAMPTZ, 
duration TIME  NOT NULL, -- Not sure about the datatype.. 
flight_id INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,

CHECK (scheduled_duration > 0),
CHECK (scheduled_arrival_time > scheduled_departure_time),

FOREIGN KEY (flight_id) REFERENCES flight(flight_id),
PRIMARY KEY (scheduled_departure_time, scheduled_arrival_time)
);
```

I want to calculate `arrival_time - departure_time` and then insert the result into the column `duration`. Preferably, the result of the duration subtraction would be `6h 30m`. I am new to databases and PostgreSQL and I can't find a way to calculate a subtraction of two timestamps, **taking into consideration their timezones** at the same time.

Comment: `select '2022-07-07 16:15'::timestamptz - '2022-07-07 09:15'::timestamptz;  07:00:00` Field type: `duration INTERVAL`. Though not sure why you want this field as it can calculated on demand. Though if you want to go this route look at [Generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-generated-columns.html) Postgres 12+.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks a lot for the heads-up! So If I was asked to calculate that difference and save it into the same table what else would I have to use as far as SQL syntax goes ? Should I take a look into functions/triggers so that the query you mentioned is run ```BEFORE INSERT``` ?

Comment: Some folks including me find the SQL standard committee’s invention of `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` type to be nonsensical. Also, be aware that the standard and implementations use offset-from-UTC rather than actual time zones. So a `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` will be wrong when politicians change the rules of a time zone which they do with surprising frequency.

Comment: Oops I was not paying attention to the `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` part. For the reasons @BasilBourque stated don't use that. Use `timestamp  with time zone` or its shortcut `timestamptz`, that is the only way to really account for time zones. The link I provided shows how you create a `GENERATED COLUMN`. That will save you having to write a trigger.

Comment: Better to store the time of day in one column, and in a second column store the [identifier of the intended time zone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). When you need to build a schedule, dynamically determine a point on the timeline by combining a date, the time, and the zone to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object. But never store that value as it becomes invalid when the politicians change the zone rules.

Comment: Also, I’m no expert on the airline industry, but… I don’t think time-of-day drives their scheduling. Scheduling planes is a game of dominoes, with one plane’s arrival impacting its next departure. So I  believe they schedule using only UTC date-times, with no zone, and an offset from UTC of zero. A time zone is applied only for presentation to a customer, but not for internal use by staff or computers. Or so I guess.

Comment: The use of `time with time zone` [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz)

Comment: Your second check constraint (scheduled_arrival_time > scheduled_departure_time) shows why you must use `timestamp with time zone` and cannot use just time.  Consider a flight with `departure_time`  of 23:00:00 (on any day); you can only store a flight of less than 1 hour because any other `arrival_time` would be less than the `departure_time` .  (And that does not consider time zone changes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generated column

```
CREATE TABLE duration
(
departure_time TIME WITH TIME ZONE, 
arrival_time TIME WITH TIME ZONE, 
scheduled_duration INT,
flight_id INT,
duration2 TIME GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("arrival_time"::time - "departure_time"::time) STORED,
CHECK (scheduled_duration > 0),
CHECK (arrival_time > departure_time),

FOREIGN KEY (flight_id) REFERENCES flight(flight_id),
PRIMARY KEY (departure_time, arrival_time)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM '2022-07-07 15:00:00.00000'::TIMESTAMP - '2022-07-07 15:00:00.00000'::TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: This results is a seconds interval that you will need to convert to something that is usable for display. So why not just do the straight subtraction of the timestamps and get a formatted interval?